# Custom conditional Keras metric

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to create the following metric for my neural network using keras

$$
s = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{\frac{-d_i}{10}}-1 & \quad d < 0 \\
            \sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{\frac{d_i}{13}}-1 & \quad d \geq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
where $d_i=y_{pred}-y_{true}$

and both $y_{pred}$ and $y_{true}$ are vectors

With the following code:

```
import keras.backend as K

    def score(y_true, y_pred):
            d=(y_pred - y_true)
            if d<0:
                return K.exp(-d/10)-1
            else:
                return K.exp(d/13)-1
```

For the use of compiling my model:

`model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[score])`

I received the following error code and I have not been able to correct the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

> raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not
>   allowed. " "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
>   "tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as "
>
> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use
>   `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,
>   and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs
>   conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming y_true and y_pred both are vectors. You are trying to apply a conditional on the value of a tensor. The library is telling you that it is not possible (tf.Tensor as Python bool).

You may want to check tensorflow control flow operations like [tensorflow.equal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal)

Answer (score 1):

`y_true` and `y_pred` are both tensors in your code.  Either change the code such that they're numpy arrays (I think this works) or look into [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), which should allow you to do the operations you're looking for on tensors.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def _loss_tensor_score(y_true, y_pred):
    y_error = y_pred - y_true
    bool_idx = K.greater(y_error, 0)
    loss1 = K.exp(-1*y_error/13) - 1 # greater 0
    loss2 = K.exp(y_error/10) - 1    # less 0
    loss = K.switch(bool_idx, loss2, loss1)
    return K.sum(loss)
```

Maybe you can try this code.

What are you doing? Remaining useful life prediction?